# why the macro definition "#define yyparse ol_parser_parse" can work?

Tags: c

Before, I did't read the generated code from [yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/) carefully.  Now I saw one snippet of code  like this:

```
#define yyparse ol_parser_parse
```

I know *yyparse*'s definition as follows:

```
int yyparse (void)
```

so, this macro definition should be interpreted as: every "ol_parser_parse" in code will be replaced by "yyparse". And I wrote some code for testing that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define yyparse ol_parser_parse
void yyparse()
{
    printf("hello world\n");
}
void main()
{
   ol_parser_parse();
}
```

It worked!
But according to the definition about ["macro definition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor):

```
#define <identifier>(<parameter list>) <replacement token list>
```

I am confused by this. Who can help me explain this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up what `ol_parser_parse` is defined as, or if it's a function too. `#define x y` substitutes `y` for `x`, not the other way around.

Comment: You have the macro definition backwards: everywhere that `yyparse` appears, the word will be changed to `ol_parser_parse`.

Comment: Its the other way round. Every yyparse is substituted by ol_parder_parse.

Comment: If `yyparse` is declared that way after the macro is defined, then that becomes `int ol_parser_parse (void)`. The macro is just there to make it easier to type, presumably.

Comment: Don't misslead with typedef, where they are `typedef <ObjectToUse> <NewName>;`. The macros are the other way. `#define <OldName> <NewName>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your code as seen by the compiler after the substitution is performed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ol_parser_parse()
{
    printf("hello world\n");
}
void main()
{
   ol_parser_parse();
}
```

There's nothing mysterious about it at that point. Every instance of "yyparse" becomes "ol_parser_parse" on every line following the `#define`.

In the documentation *identifier* means the thing being substituted and *replacement token list* is what you're substituting it with. You can also have parameters, like:

```
#define TIMES_TWO(n) ((n) * 2)
```

Where you can then do:

```
int x = TIMES_TWO(3);
```

Where that's equivalent to:

```
int x = ((3) * 2);
```

Where the extra brackets are so you can do this and not mess up order of operations:

```
int x = TIMES_TWO(1 - 5);
```

Without the brackets it'd show up as this:

```
int x = 1 - 5 * 2;
```

Which evaluates to `1 - 10` which is not what you want.

There's an art to using `#define` effectively to hide otherwise ugly implementation details. The name `ol_parser_parse` isn't something you need to worry about if you can use the `yyparser` macro. That gives the implementers the freedom to rename that function and the corresponding macro without breaking all your code.